# Override image feed into Vuforia in Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, tracking, playback, vuforia

I want to record the video feed captured from Vuforia then play the scene back, allowing for the tracked image marker to be enabled or disabled upon playback. I know Vuforia allows me to access camera properties with `Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance` but there doesn't seem to be a way to override the incoming image with a prerecorded one.

I know I could record the state (position and rotation) of the objects during the recording but it seems more elegant for them to be tracking in realtime based off a prerecorded video feed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted this as well, to no avail.

From: [Is is possible to use Vuforia without a camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536257/is-is-possible-to-use-vuforia-without-a-camera)

> ...but the Vuforia SDK prevents the use of any other source than the camera.
>
> I guess the main reason for this is that the camera management is fully handled internally by the Vuforia SDK, probably in order to make it easier to use as managing the camera by ourselves is at best a boring task (lines and lines of code to repeat in each project...), at worst a huge pain in the ass (especially on Android where there are sometimes devices than don't behave as expected).

Comment: @EdwinChua Maybe my answer could help?

Comment: @Hristo the question, to my understanding, was asking whether Vuforia can run it's AR capabilities on a video feed, instead of the camera view. i.e. detect a marker on a pre-recorded video

Comment: @EdwinChua You are correct! I misunderstood what OP wanted to achieve.